# Django Регистрация/авторизация через VK (rest_framework_social_oauth2)

Tags: python-3.x, django, вконтакте, django-rest-framework, oauth2

Я успешно регистрирую/авторизую пользователя через метод convert-token. Передаю следующие поля:

```
{
    "grant_type": "convert_token",
    "client_id": "client_id",
    "backend": "vk-oauth2",
    "token": "token"
}
```

В ответ приходит:

```
{
    access_token: "access_token",
    expires_in: 36000,
    refresh_token: "refresh_token",
    scope: "read write",
    token_type: "Bearer"
}
```

У меня возникли следующие вопросы:

1. Как обновить токен, использую refresh_token. В документации не нашел ничего про это?
2. Можно ли где-то указать, чтобы использовался jwt token, а не bearer?